# Recenter a named buffer that is not necessarily the current buffer in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to recenter a buffer, called `*Lense*`, where I've inserted some text. I wished to make it the current buffer by `(set-buffer "*Lense*")`, then `(recenter 0))`.  By the following code segments:

```
(save-excursion (set-buffer "*Lense*")
                (recenter 0))
```

However, it seems that the above code would only recenter the buffer which is the current buffer, and `(set-buffer "*Lense*")` has no effect to make the current buffer to be `*Lense*`.

Please help me to figure out the right way to recenter the named buffer `*Lense*`.

Comment: I found an answer now. The following code would do the job:
(save-excursion (pop-to-buffer "*Lense*")
                (goto-char (point-max))
                (recenter 0))

The key is to use "pop-to-buffer". The behavior of "set-buffer" is confusing, not reliable.

Comment: The confusion is caused by the different contexts. `set-buffer` selects *buffer* for editing operations and `recenter` works on *window* not buffer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the buffer you want to recenter is visible, then you want to recenter its window.

```
(with-selected-window (get-buffer-window "*Lense*")
  (recenter 0))
```

This will blow up if the buffer is not being displayed, so you may want to condition-case or unwind-protect.

If you want to handle the case where the buffer is not visible,  you need to move the point.  The window that will eventually display the buffer will center near the point, so you will have to move the point somewhere that will make that happen.  Seems like your insert operation will DTRT, so you don't need to worry in that case.

Comment: This is a good solution. It meets my need. The buffer "*Lense*" is visible. Thanks a lot! Yu

Comment: You don't need to use `condition-case` or `unwind-protect`. Assuming that you only want to recenter a buffer that is in fact displayed, just make the code conditional on that: `(when (get-buffer-window "*Lense*" 'visible)...`.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found *(recenter)* function, but there is *(recenter-top-bottom)*. You can try using it instead of *(recenter)*. Standard C-l hotkey calls exactly this function *(recenter-top-bottom)*, also it has optional argument, line of window, which can be passed by C-u *arg* C-l.
PS: I can be wrong because I'm not familiar with emacs-lisp, I'm just using emacs with minimal customizations.

Comment: I believe the *recenter* functions have recently undergone ome name changes, so there is a version dependency here...

Comment: `recenter is an interactive built-in function in `window.c'.`

Comment: I was responsible for adding `recenter-top-bottom` and binding it to `C-l`. Command `recenter` still exists, as jrockway indicates; it just is no longer bound by default to `C-l`.